# VSCode bash terminal text turns invisible

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

On VS Code's bash windows if I run a command that returns a long response like "git log" and interrupt it with double tapping ctrl + C then everything I type is invisible. Bash works as I can type "clear" and get a response for any command but I cannot see my text.

I am currently forced to delete the terminal and insert another one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is not a great answer, but it's most definitely a bug.

You can see here that the integrated terminal VSCode uses in Windows is still under very active development: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45693

The currently tracked bugs do include colour and 'invisibility' issues, as well as issues surrounding command termination (`ctrl+c`) recovery.

VS Code is an OpenSource project, and has a fairly responsive and helpful community for getting bugs fixed. It looks like this bug specifically hasn't been raised before (although, as mentioned, variants have), so it'd be helpful for the team if you raised it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues so that someone can take a look and get it fixed!

Comment: Thanks, I will raise an issue there. My question wasn't that great as your answer.

Answer (score 40):

Solution that helped me is to change `terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration` in settings to `off`

Comment: I just updated VS Code today to version `1.85.1` and suddenly when I type in terminal characters are invisible until after I type 15 or so characters it flickers to being visible. It had never been an issue before on Ubuntu ARM64. This solution worked but I wonder why?

Answer (score 10):

Some text in integrated terminal is invisible: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44273

- VS Code Version: 1.67.2
- OS Version: Win10
- Laptop: Asus K53SV

Temporary solution:

- File > References > Settings (or Ctrl + ,)
- Type: terminal.integrated.gpu
- Set one to off

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer. My man provided a buglink, version number, click path AND an gif.  10/10 would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you will meet this problem that will occurs you a seriously bad behavior with your computer mousse, isn't it ?

Solution for me :

1. `code --disable-gpu` write this in command line, it will works i hope.
2. Update your machine, Update VSCODE and pray for works.

If it doesn't works, tell me what are you seeing.